# Entity Framework 4.0 (5.0) and one-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many

I have two classes:

```
public class MultilingualString
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string DefaultText { get; set; }

  public IList<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Translation
{
    public string Language { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MultilingualString Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'd like to have tables MultilingualStrings and Translations with the following schema:

```
MultilingualString
  ID INT PK
  DefaultText NVARCHAR
```

and

```
Translations
  StringID PK, FK
  Language NCHAR(5) PK
  Text NVARCHAR
```

But don't know how to create my code first model mapping with EF4/EF5. Is this scenario possible with EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to create a mapping between your tables and your entities because you must expose the full primary key as property/properties in your entity classes. Your table `Translations` has a composite primary key (`StringID`+`Language`) but your entity `Translation` only has a part of this key (`Language`) as a property.

However, if you introduce the `StringID` as property in `Translation` the mapping should be possible:

```
public class Translation
{
    public int StringId { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MultilingualString Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.StringId, t.Language });

modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
    .Property(t => t.Language)
    .HasMaxLength(5)
    .IsFixedLength();

modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Owner)
    .WithMany(m => m.Translations)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.StringId);
```

Comment: Basically it works. But, is there any way to hide the StringId property from the user? I find this as another limitation of EF against NH...

Comment: @Roland: You can't remove StringId completely. I am not sure if you can make the property non-public. `internal` probably yes, if model class and EF mapping code are in the same assembly. I don't know if `protected` or `private` is possible. I remember that there were changes about visibility in EF >= 4.3. If you want to be sure, better ask this as a new question.